# Unable to show Images stored in mySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, blob, wampserver

I am trying to store images in mySQL database and then displaying on the other page. I have this function to store images in mySQL.

```
 function upload() {
        include "databaseConnection.php";
        $maxsize = 10000000; //set to approx 10 MB
        //check associated error code
        if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

            //check whether file is uploaded with HTTP POST
            if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

                //checks size of uploaded image on server side
                if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] < $maxsize) {


                    // prepare the image for insertion
                    $imgData = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

                    // put the image in the db...
                    // database connection
                    mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) OR DIE(mysql_error());

                    // select the db
                    mysql_select_db($db) OR DIE("Unable to select db" . mysql_error());

                    // our sql query
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO carsinfo
                (carName, carPicture)
                VALUES
                ('{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}', '{$imgData}');";

                    // insert the image
                    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
                    $msg = '<p>Image successfully saved in database with id =' . mysql_insert_id() . ' </p>';
                } else {
                    // if the file is not less than the maximum allowed, print an error
                    $msg = '<div>File exceeds the Maximum File limit</div>
            <div>Maximum File limit is ' . $maxsize . ' bytes</div>
            <div>File ' . $_FILES['userfile']['name'] . ' is ' . $_FILES['userfile']['size'] .
                            ' bytes</div><hr />';
                }
            }
            else
                $msg = "File not uploaded successfully.";
        }
        else {
            $msg = file_upload_error_message($_FILES['userfile']['error']);
        }
        return $msg;
    }
```

And this code to show iamges.

```
    <?php
    include "databaseConnection.php";
    // just so we know it is broken
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    // some basic sanity checks
    //connect to the db
    $link = mysql_connect("$host", "$user", "$pass") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

    // select our database
    mysql_select_db("$db") or die(mysql_error());
    // get the image from the db
    $sql = "SELECT carPicture FROM carsinfo;";
    // the result of the query
    $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // set the header for the image
    echo $row['carPicture'];
    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    // close the db link
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

When this code is run, nothing is shown on the page, even if I write some HTML inside this code, empty page is shown.

Comment: Why not store the images on your server, or some external server, and just store the path to the image?

Comment: I know that method but this is my university assignment to store images in DB and then show.
Image is stored perfectly as I can see from loclhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are saving the image content as blob and if your sql is returning the correct data then you can display as

```
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['carPicture'];
```

You need to add the header first before the image.

or

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode($row['carPicture']) . '">';
```

Comment: Tried this too. But does not work. Yes, image is stored as BLOD in DB.

Comment: Are you sure your query is getting executed ? and more over your query is SELECT carPicture FROM carsinfo; and it will try to get all the data from that table, and your $row data may be empty for the image since you are not looping the result set.

Comment: query is executed as I checked using if($result)
Can you please check the upload fucntion in my question.

Comment: Code looks good, only thing, do not use addslashes() , use mysql_real_escape_string(), $imgData = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));

Comment: And also change the datatype to LONGBLOB for carPicture then try uploading

Comment: Did so too! does not work.
I checked the image size and the size of the tuple in carImage, those are equal(I guess it shows that image is uploaded successfully).
Now, problem might be with showing the image.

Comment: No the image should display if there is a data in your $row, try to do the query as  SELECT carPicture FROM carsinfo order by {your table primary key } desc limit 1, your query will select all data and echo $row['carPicture']; will contain the first table record which may not have the record for image ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45543/discussion-between-user3110335-and-abhik-chakraborty)

Answer (score 0):

do not write 
include `databaseConnection.php`

nothing include anything.

Comment: please fix the spelling mistake "don not"